# Why are accepts excluded from the daily reputation cap?

Tags: discussion, reputation, accepted-answer, daily-reputation-limit

Why are accepted answers (giving a total of (+15 rep (answer) + +2 rep (question) = ) +17 rep) excluded from the daily reputation cap?

From the help center:

> You can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day from the combination of upvotes, downvotes and suggested edits. But Bounty awards, **accepted answers**, and association bonuses are not subject to this daily reputation limit.
>
> - *https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation*

The question posters know that this answer fixes their problem, and therefore accepts the answer. But why would the daily reputation cap exclude accepts? I understand why bounties would be excluded, because they can be beyond the reputation cap by themselves (anywhere up to +500 rep), but why  would accepts be?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The idea of rep cap is to prevent overly large gains from a post that happens to be very popular (social network effect, etc). Accept is not a problem here, as there is just one per answer. If someone posts 100 answers in a day and they are all accepted... That is probably not a problem.

Comment: or if it is, it's because it's a voting ring, and voting rings accepting 100 answers a day **will** get spotted rapidly

Comment: not only that, but it would be a slap in the face for very productive and experienced users, if they get rep-blocked for taking medium to high effort in forming a correct and appropriate answer. May reduce motivation on certain individuals.

Comment: I do not take it as a slap in the face. I rather take it as a protection against as inexperienced users who try to get spurious reputation. In facts, SOF diagnoses every thing that is usually repetitive as a fake.

Comment: @AlainD How can the rep earned by _accepted_ answers ever be spurious? inexperienced user or not, if the answer is correct and good enough to be an accepted answer, why should one try to protect against that (other than the previously mentioned vote-rings)? The ability to misuse this, would be in hands of the OP, not the answerer.

Comment: "If someone posts 100 answers in a day and they are all accepted..." Sure it is. It's almost certainly the result of spoon feeding help vampires with low quality code dump answers (barring actual fraud, of course).

Comment: votes are more often abused, because they are anonymous, but accept votes are visibly linked to a person

Comment: @jpmc26: in my experience most help vampires aren't typically that obliging as to accept answers.

Comment: @D.Schaller. How to get 100 accepted answers is easy. Your buddy asks 100 questions, you answer them and your buddy validates. Every thing done in unusually large quantity is suspicious. The rule is : You can do but your earn nothing.

Comment: @AlainD which would be a (kinda small) vote-ring, so that scenario is already covered in Patrice's previous comment. And I never mentioned a specific number. I'm just saying capping accepted answers would be kinda rude to those, who are really productive.

Comment: one of the ideas behind the rep cap was [removing incentive for obsessive behaviour](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/136060). giving rep for accepted answers doesnt help with that.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from stopping privileges gained in one day from one zeitgeist matching question or answer resulting in people with power but no knowledge of how the system works.

The other reason accepts are excluded is to encourage the continued participation of those few individuals who would otherwise always receive 200 rep every day from their large cache of previous good posts. The only way they can gain rep more quickly than that is to get accepts and bounties, both of which require them to keep answering.